# Problem with printing char inside if-condition

Tags: c, cs50

I have an assignment to cipher letters according to a formula. We are suppose to keep uppercases as uppercases and lowercases as lowercases.
The formula for ciphering is this: ci = (pi + k) % 26.

Int x in my code is k.

Pi is the character in the string.

Right now im facing two problems. The cipher  is currently not working (and and the code is not done).
**But the chars are not printing.**  Highly appriciate if you could look at it and give me some clues about why its not printing.

This is my code:

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


char cipher (string plaintext, int x);
int main (int argc, string argv [])

{
 //here is part for validation

//GET STRING


//CRYPT
  string plaintext = get_string ("plaintext: ");

    for(int i= 0; i < strlen(plaintext); i++)
    {

      int ci = 0;
      int ch = 65;

      if (isupper(plaintext[i]))
     {
         if (x <= 26 - (plaintext[i] - ch))
        {
            ci = plaintext[i] + x;
            printf("%c", plaintext[ci]);
        }

     //if the key is overflowing the letters left in alpha

        else if (x > 26 - (plaintext[i] - ch))
        {
            ci = ((plaintext[i] + x) % 26) + 64;
            printf("%c", plaintext[ci]);
        }


    }

 
   }




}
```

Comment: What is `x`? You start using it in an `if` in `main`, but it was never defined nor set in `main`, only in the not shown `cipher` function.

Comment: Hey it is defined earlier in the text that i did not publish here.

Comment: Why do you subtract 26? This looks wrong to me, because you already subtract 65 from the character which gives you a range between 0..26. Subtracting another 26, would underflow the value IMO.

Comment: Yes that part of the code was wrong.

Comment: This code might be easier to understand, and think about, if it used the values `'A'` and `'a'` which evaluate to the ASCII values of the letters you need to handle. The values `26` and `65` are difficult to follow.

Answer (score 2):

The lines

```
            printf("%c", plaintext[ci]);
```

are wrong. `ci` here is already the character code to print, so they should be

```
            printf("%c", ci);
```

or more simply

```
            putchar(ci);
```

Comment: Thank u! Now its  printing but still wrong hehe.